# Does the heart play a role in the occurrence of emotions?

Tags: emotion, physiology

It is a common belief that the heart is somehow related to emotions. When we are nervous,our heartbeat is effected (increased heart rate) and when we are happy, another pattern in heart function can be observed.

My question is the following. Does the heart have a significant role in the occurence of emotions, or is it that the heart is just an organ that pumps blood and these physiological changes are merely a by-product of processes relevant to emotion?
Is the heart's function of interest to any cognitive scientific field of study?

Comment: Welcome to cogsci.SE!  I'm not sure what you're asking--are you asking what changes in heartbeat can tell us about emotion?

Comment: Are you asking for a link between the function of the heart and cognitive function or affect? Your question might be related to this http://m.pnas.org/content/111/2/646 Take a look..

Comment: Or are you asking the symbolism of heart ❤️? Many symbolism such as care, long-lasting, empathy, love and so on are related to emotions. If you think two people hugging/kissing each other or being very close, their outline in a way forms a heart -- does it explain the origin or feelings associated with it? Attachement, feeling of belonging.

Comment: Let me make it more clear, 
Is there any space for heart in cognitive sciences ? 
or its just an organ to pump blood?

Comment: The heart is as relevant as any of your other muscles for emotional processes - so it is **not** really relevant to the cognitive sciences. Basically, it's just an organ to pump blood (and a symptom of certain emotional states).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been pointed in the other answers and the comments, the heart is indeed only an organ that pumps blood and all the processes responsible for emotions are carried out [by the brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion#Neurocircuitry). However, the heart and generally the autonomous nervous system is of critical importance to [somatic theories of emotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion#Somatic_theories). These theories propose that bodily responses in the presence of a certain stimulus, initiate emotional processing. However, it is not that the heart, for instance, creates an emotion. It is the brain that notices any significant physiological changes like the heart rate being increased and makes an interpretation of this internal state taking into account the available stimuli. This idea originates with [William James' theory of emotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Lange_theory) but it was also incorporated in more recent approaches like the [somatic marker hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_marker_hypothesis#Working_mechanism) by Antonio Damasio.

Answer (score 0):

Emotions are attached to heart.

Eg. if you feel scared in dangerous situation, [sympathetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_nervous_system) part of [autonomic nervous system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomic_nervous_system) is activated. It increases heart rate and then blood flow to brain is elevated. More blood transports more oxygen and then brain functions better.